# Which vs a comma

Tags: commas, clauses

I was going through a test and came upon this question:

> Unfortunately, one of those species is the 
>   **Bark Scorpion, just about the only species** whose venom is 
>   considered truly dangerous and often fatal to humans.

Here are the choices to replace the bold part of the sentence:

> - A. NO CHANGE
> - B. Bark Scorpion which is just about the only species
> - C. only one that is the Bark Scorpion species,
> - D. Bark Scorpion, yet just about the only species

The test picks B as the right answer. While I do not see a problem with B, I do not see a problem with A. NO CHANGE as well. Can anyone explain to me why answer choice A is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I see B as an alternative, but nothing wrong with the sentence as is.  I think perhaps A is considered wrong because it implies that B is not an acceptable alternative.

Comment: Does B really come without a comma before "which"?  Which in this sentence is a non-restrictive relative pronoun.  A C- for the exam writer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing this is from an ACT. For the purposes of the ACT, typically only non-essential appositives should be between 2 commas. as written, the phrase "one...Scorpion" is between 2 commas, but it is not a non-essential appositive. Answer choices C and D would also create this problem of placing the phrase between 2 commas even though it is not a non-essential appositive. Answer choice B is the only one that does not result in this issue.